# Java Script while using ENVDTE - Add new project to existing solution and locate it in a specific sub-folder

Tags: javascript, c++, wizard, solution, envdte

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension of a new c++ project template on Visual Studio 2010. I 'm doing it by the method of .vsz template. I expanded the default.js code according to my needs. iN THE OnFinish(selProj, selObj) function I copy an existing solution from some directory in my computer to the current solution directory, I add the new generated project to that solution, and run it.

I'm doing this like:

```
function OnFinish(selProj, selObj) {

    try
    {
        var strProjectPath = wizard.FindSymbol('PROJECT_PATH');
        var strProjectName = wizard.FindSymbol('PROJECT_NAME');


        selProj = CreateCustomProject(strProjectName, strProjectPath);
        AddConfig(selProj, strProjectName);
        AddFilters(selProj);

        var InfFile = CreateCustomInfFile();
        AddFilesToCustomProj(selProj, strProjectName, strProjectPath, InfFile);
        PchSettings(selProj);
        InfFile.Delete();

        selProj.Object.Save();



        debugger;
        //My Added Code
        var strSolutionPath = strProjectPath + "\\..";
        var EmulationPath = "C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\TestSln";
        var TreePath = strSolutionPath + "\\apps";
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        fso.CopyFolder(EmulationPath, strSolutionPath);

        var Solution = dte.Solution;
        Solution.Open(strSolutionPath + "\\TestSln.sln");

        var p = Solution.AddFromFile(strProjectPath + "\\" + strProjectName + ".vcxproj"); 


    }
    catch(e)
    {
        if (e.description.length != 0)
            SetErrorInfo(e);
        return e.number
    }
}
```

but I have to add the new project to a specific sub-folder of the solution: the above code adds the new project to the solution straightly, and I'ld like to add it to the solutionDir\apps. BTW, the "apps" folder is empty, and I want it to contain the new generated project from now on.

Do you know about any way to do thus? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= solution.Projects.Count; i++) 
        {
            if(Solution.Projects.Item(i).Name == "apps")        
            {
                appsFolder = Solution.Projects.Item(i);
                project = appsFolder.Object.AddFromFile(newProjectPath + "\\" + strProjectName + "\\" + strProjectName + ".vcxproj");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Thanks you all for trying help :)